# Joomla JCE add custom component data to link browser

Tags: joomla, hyperlink, joomla1.6

I am using Joomla 1.6 along with JCE 2.0.15

I also have created my own component and I want to be able to link to pages from this component and to be more precise, I would like them to appear in the link browser window:

[image]

Basically I just need to be able to let users enter links to stuff from my component to articles without forcing them to make a menu entry in a hidden menu for each piece they want to link to (which I now see as a pretty bad alternative).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the developer of JCE [the same question](http://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/forum/jce-plugins--addons/creating-a-link-plugin-ala-jce-15) - the answer is you can do it, but there is no documentation.

As a guide he suggests looking at some of the [existing 3rd Party Extensions for JCE 2.x](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/jce-extensions) as a guide.